# Can I convert HDMI output to something that I could read into a USB port?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to use a Raspberry Pi (RP) as an SSH server, but I don't have an HDMI or RCA monitor/TV to use with it. It is possible to convert the HDMI/RCA output of the Raspberry Pi to USB that can be read by my computer (a laptop) so I won't need a monitor or TV?

Once the initial setup is complete, I'll be able to remote into the RP and finish my setup remotely.

Comment: When you say you don't have a monitor/tv to use with it, do you mean a monitor/tv with an HDMI connection?  Because there is an RCA video connection too.

Comment: I don't have a monitor or a TV with an HDMI connection or an RCA connection.

Comment: RCA capture devices are rather inexpensive if you want to go that route. A new monitor would be cheaper than HDMI capture device if you insist on using HDMI out.

Comment: If I get an RCA to USB cable, how does that work? Would I just hook it up from the RP to my computer and watch the output using VLC (or some other media app)? I'll won't need instant refresh, but something better than still frames.

Comment: Why don't you just remote into the Raspberry Pi?  I don't understand where the USB port is suppose to come into play.

Comment: I also don't understand what you want to do with the USB port.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I remote into it before anything is set up? I presume it will come with an OS installed, but unless the OS is automatically configured for remote access, I'll still need to see some output temporarily in order to complete the set up.

Comment: @Shinrai I edited my question to try to clear it up.

Comment: OH, okay, that makes sense now.  I am not aware of any way to do what you're asking, though.

Comment: @Shinrai What about an RCA to USB cable? Another user (Alex) mentioned one of those above. Would that work?

Comment: @Frank - The issue is that there's nothing really designed to accept real-time video over USB since USB isn't an AV standard (a video capture card of some sort might work, but that's still going to require an expenditure)

Answer (score 2):

Converting either the (HDMI) digital video or (yellow "RCA") composite video to anything else (e.g. VGA) is going to involve a converter box that is going to cost more than a serial port connection.  There is simply no converter for video out to USB into anything besides video capture devices.

You're asking an XY question.
What you really want to accomplish is to use something besides a video port as the console.
The simple solution is to use the RP's UART as the console, and then use a TTL converter to RS-232 or USB to connect to PC/laptop. Directions are [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) and [here](http://www.element14.com/community/groups/raspberry-pi/blog/2012/07/18/look-ma-no-display-using-the-raspberry-pi-serial-console) and [here](http://codeandlife.com/2012/07/01/raspberry-pi-serial-console-with-max3232cpe/).  An all-in-a-cable assembly is this [USB converter](http://www.adafruit.com/products/954) (photo is below text).  A UART for the console is a common/standard procedure for bringing up embedded or single board computers.

The serial port connection has the added benefit of consolidating input and output so that you no longer need to attach a keyboard and mouse.  The downside is that you now have a text interface rather than a GUI; however that is typical for a server. 
[image]

Another solution is to use [a networked console over Ethernet](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt).

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with the RP at all, will it support this outside of an OS?  That is, can you use it to install the OS in the first place?

Comment: @Shinrai - The RP's OS is installed on the removable SD card. There is no need to use the serial console for transferring binaries, although that could be possible with a capable terminal emulator program on the PC side (e.g. minicom or teraterm) and a "xmodem" or similar program on the RP. But the serial port is intended to be used a console, and only a transfer method of last resort.  For example, a lot of ARM SBCs can use U-Boot with a serial-port console and can *tftp* a Linux kernel and initramfs image using the network